# std::regex_replace: access index of disjunct match groups

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, boost

I've been tasked with replacing boost::regex with std::regex and hit an issue with boost::regex references to capture group indexes.

The regex looks like that:

```
re = "(^Match1$)|(^Match2$)|(^Match3$)|(^Match4$)"
```

With a replace string:

```
replace_str = "(?{1}M1)(?{2}M2)(?{3}M3)(?{4}M4)"
```

If I call `boost::regex_replace("Match1", re, replace_str, format_all)`
i get "M1" as result and with `std::regex_replace("Match1", re, replace_str)` the result consists of the whole replace_str.

The standardized variant of regex does not have the format_all option (not sure if that is the issue). 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type

How do I reproduce a similar behaviour with the c++11/14 regex library? 
Have I missed an option or syntax that does allow to use that behaviour without boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`std::regex` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) does not support  [Boost-Extended Format String Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html) that is supported by Boost regex engine.

If you are looking for an alternative to Boost, you may consider switching to PCRE2 that supports a similar conditional replacement pattern syntax. See PCRE2 [Extended Replacement String Syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre2.html#subext) article.